# Can I split config.groovy file of grails?

Tags: grails

As there is sensitive code in the `config.groovy` file, I am afraid that my friends will commit with bugs in this file. When getting **svn** update, we too will get the buggy config code.

Can i split the code at `config.groovy` in such a way that the sensitive code remains untouched and the other can be changed frequently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to Marijn's answer.  This is how I usually set up my Config.groovy.  I still use it for some settings, but anything environmentally (deployment location or individual machine) changing can override any settings in the Config.groovy.

Config.groovy  >>>>

```
grails.config.locations = [
        "file:../app-config/myapp-dataSource.groovy",
        "file:../app-config/myapp-config.groovy"
]

environments {
  development {
    grails.config.locations = [
            "file:../myapp-config/myapp-dataSource.groovy",
            "file:../myapp-config/myapp-config.groovy",
            "file:${userHome}/myapp-config/myapp-dataSource.groovy",
            "file:${userHome}/myapp-config/myapp-config.groovy"
    ]   
    some.config.setting=true
  }
}
```

file:${userHome}/myapp-config/myapp-config.groovy >>>>

```
some.config.setting=false
```

Comment: hey! Nick, thanks buddy it finally worked when i sent it in a list as u mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Inside your main config file you are able to access this variable:

```
grails.config.locations
```

It is a list of configuration file locations to which you can add your own files:

```
grails.config.locations << 'file:MyConfigFile.groovy'
```

These files will then be added to your configuration.

For a more elaborate setup see this blog post:
 http://www.pasopas.nl/2012/loading-grails-configuration-files-update/

Comment: thank you!!  but i am still confused on getting grails.config.locations << 'file:MyConfigFile.groovy'